# Is there a way of binding all double click events to their single click equivalent in jQuery / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have some jQuery with a lot of different click events. Some of my users are habitual double clickers, which because I have no double click events bound, fires the single click event twice; this can be a pain - for example if one click opens something, and another closes it, double clicking is a zero-sum game.

Is there any way to bind all double click events to their single click equivalent without have the code them individually?

Comment: You've said that my now-deleted answer (`$(document).on("dblclick", false);`) works for you despite my realizing (and jcubic confirming) that it's just plain wrong. You said *"Perhaps it's working because of the way I've bound my events? $(document).on("click", ".likePost", function(event) {"* But that [still doesn't work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/3yh9up53/1/). I think it must be observational error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yep, you were right (in that you were wrong). It was something else that was making it appear to work if I double clicked quickly enough - a slightly slower dbl click (but still fast enough to register as a dblclick) presented the same issue. I'm wondering if a timeout on all click events might do the job?

Comment: (The first click changes the class which changes the event, if I double clicked quickly enough, I was still hitting the first event).

Comment: maybe you can prevent click for certain amount of time using settimeout

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mapping dblclick to click would help; I'd think it would make things worse, if anything.

You've said you hook up your events using delegation. You could give yourself a function that debounces calls to your event handler:

```js
// Very simple debounce, accepts first event and disregards
// subsequent ones for a period of time
function debouncedHandler(handler, delay) {
  delay = delay || 300; // milliseconds, I'm told Windows uses 500 but that seems awfully long
  var last;
  return function() {
    var now = Date.now();
    if (last && last + delay > now) {
      return false;
    }
    last = now;
    return handler.apply(this, arguments);
  };
}

$(document).on("click", "input[type=button]", debouncedHandler(function() {
  $(".container").toggleClass("toggle-open toggle-closed");
}));
```

```css
.toggle-open .closed {
  display: none;
}
.toggle-closed .open {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Open/Close">
<div class="container toggle-open">
  <span class="open">OPEN</span>
  <span class="closed">closed</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn">
click me
</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var clickDisabled = false;
   $('.btn').click(function(){
      if (clickDisabled)
         return;

      // do your real click processing here
            console.log('hi');
      clickDisabled = true;
      setTimeout(function(){clickDisabled = false;}, 5000);
  });

});
```

kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/05tvvaeq/

preventing  click handler for 5secs (you can set the time as per your need)
check console to see the result

Answer (score -1):

This is what I would do it:

```
<input type="hidden" id='counter' value='0'>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save()">

function save(){
var counter = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").value);
counter = counter+1;

if(counter == 1){
console.log('Saving...')
}

document.getElementById("counter").value = counter;

//after 3 seconds set counter back to 0
     setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("counter").value = 0;

    }, 3000)
}
```